# Regex to select URLs without traling slashes

Tags: regex, string

I have the following types urls patterns in the response received from a api call.

```
https://www.someurl.com/path-one/path-two/test/
https://www.someurl.com/path-one/path-two/test
https://www.someurl.com/path-one/self-care/anotherpath/fitness/best-postpartum-apps#
https://www.someurl.com/path-one/self-care?category=best-postpartum-apps#
```

I want a regex that can capture only the second from the top url pattern, i.e `https://www.someurltwo.com/path-one/path-two/test`

Tried this regex but the selection is incorrect as it captures all the patterns above - `https?:\/\/(www.)?someurl\.com\/(?:.*\/)?[^\/.]+$`

Comment: sometimes the url is just `https://someurl.com/path-one/path-two/test` so that capturing group is to catch both situations - with or without `www`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?someurl\.com(?:\/[^?#\/\r\n]+)+$
```

`^` start of a line/string.

`https?` match http or https.

`:\/\/` match `://`.

`(?:www\.)?` non-capturing group, match an optional `www.` group.

`someurl\.com` match `someurl.com`

`(?:\/[^?#\/\r\n]+)+`

- `(?:` start of a non-capturing group.

  - `\/[^?#\/\r\n]+`

    - `\/` a forward slash `/` followed by:
    - `[^?#\/\r\n]+` one or more character that is not `?`, `#`, `/`, `\r` or `\n`. Note `\r\n` for line terminators.
- `)` end of the capturing group.
- the `+` after the `)` means repeat the group one or more times.

`$` end of a line/string.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0uVkq4/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want ULRs that contains trailing slashes please use

```
.*[^/]$
```

for example in Python:

```
".*[^/]$"gm
```

Description:

- `[]`: match each char from the brackets `[]`
- `[^]`: match each char except these between brackets
- `[^/]`: match each char except the slashes
- `[^/]$`: match each char on the end of the line except the slashes
- `[^/]$`: match the whole line (all characters) that not have slashes on the end of the line

But you asked you want match only the second URL - I suppose You don't want to trailing hashes char too. Then try this:

```
.*[^/#]$
```

Description like above + not have trailing hashes.